# getting Jacobian from lmfit minimizer

Tags: python, scipy-optimize, lmfit

lmfit Minimizer is built on top of scipy.optimize. So,

```
import lmfit
params = lmfit.Parameters()
params.add('param', ...)
result = lmfit.minimize(fcn, params, method="least_squares")
```

calls scipy.optimize.least_squares. The latter outputs, among other things, the Jacobian in OptimizeResult.jac. However, can I access the Jacobian when using lmfit, too, or is that information lost?

Answer (score 0):

The ModelResult class has an optional callable function `jacfcn`. You can call this on your `result` to calculate the jacobian array [according to the documentation.](https://lmfit.github.io/lmfit-py/model.html?highlight=jacobian#lmfit.model.jacfcn)

Comment: I'm missing something: lmfit.minimize returns an instance of class MinimizerResult, but jacfcn is an attribute of ModelResult. How can I access jacfcn, then, from result? Thanks.

Comment: Ahh sorry I misread the question. If you make a model from your function (see [https://lmfit.github.io/lmfit-py/model.html?highlight=jacobian#the-model-class](https://lmfit.github.io/lmfit-py/model.html?highlight=jacobian#the-model-class)), you can then use Model.fit() which returns a ModelResult object (which you can then use to access jacfcn)

Comment: I'm triangulating a point from other known locations. Not really a curve-fitting problem.

Answer (score 0):

With `lmfit.least_squares`, the jacobian is currently not preserved.

May I ask why you think you want this and what do you expect to be able to do with it?  The covariance matrix is calculated and included in the returned MinimizerResult (`result.covar`), and the uncertainties and correlations between all parameters are already calculated as well.

Comment: The inversion has a nullspace. So, I already split it into sequential ones and now want to modify the inversion results by adding prior information along the lines of Tarantola, Inverse Problems, 3.2.1: (Jacobian^T * data covariance ^ -1 * data residual + model covariance ^ -1 * model update) / normalization. In this way the prior information should stabilize the inversions. Alternatively I bake the priors into the cost function.

Comment: I think you are asking to access the Jacobian during the fit, at each function evaluation.  As far as I understand, that is not possible with any method unless you are calculating the Jacobian on your own. Basically, you want to have another fitting *method* that adds such prior information.   Getting the Jacobian evaluated at the best solution (which is what `least_squares` would return) is probably not going to be helpful.

Comment: Oh, yes, a least_squares-with-priors fitting method would be wonderful! Instead, short of writing my own Jacobian, I thought I could break the optimization after the first iteration via iter_cb, but, I now see, iter_cb is called after each evaluation of fcn rather than after each iteration, as you have explained before. Instead, can I set ftol to infinity so as to make lmfit exit gracefully after the first iteration, modify the update as above, and wrap both steps into a loop?

Comment: By the way, lmfit with the method "least_squares" does return the Jacobian in MinimizerResult.jac. Undocumented and maybe not intentional, but it's there.

Comment: "iteration" is poorly defined and not something the caller can reliably determine.  "function evaluation" is clear.  If I understand correctly, you are looking for is a different cost function that depends on not only the current residual but the Jacobian (derivatives of that residual).   As far as I know, none of the available methods use the Jacobian in the evaluation of the cost, and I don't really understand why that would be useful.  I think you're looking for a different fitting method, but maybe I simply don't understand what you are trying to do.

Comment: I'm sorry, but see [pylops](https://pylops.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorials/bayesian.html) or [Tarantola, Inverse Problem Theory, 3.2.3](http://www.ipgp.fr/~tarantola/Files/Professional/Books/index.html). Update iteratively the model as in the former paper and above. Alternatively, minimize the cost function w1 * (data residual) ** 2 + w2 * (model update) ** 2. Now, I am using the latter, no need for a Jacobian, and it seems to work well! Thanks for your answers.